# Set same gap between each point of x axis data in Flot Js

Tags: javascript, flot

My graph is as below :

[image]

I want to make an same gap between each point in flot because I want to show only 6 data at the same time.
So I can manage the look of my x axis data.
Right now this is not looking good.
You can give me another solution for making an x axis label values looking good.

Comment: Please add your code and data, as a code snippet or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) if possible.

Comment: Rather than add the x axis values as time values have you tried using numeric values with a custom formatter?

Comment: I want xaxis values as it is.
Haven't try with custom formatter.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uv0fq2kf/1/ this is my fiddle.

Comment: @Raidri, please advice on this fiddle.

Comment: Do you want your data points evenly spread over the x axis or only the x axis labels (which would mean that the x axis labels are no longer directly below a data point)?

Comment: I want like same distance between each points as well as on x axis.
Because i have set it to fixed like display only 6 data/points in chart.
So it is ok if there is same gap for  me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to display linear x values in flot is to provide flot with an ascending index then use this index combined with a custom label function to display whatever string you want as the x axis label. The code to do this looks like the following:

```
function randomDate() {
    var start = new Date(2012, 01, 01);
    var end = new Date();
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}

$(function () {
    var theDates = [];
    var dataValues = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
        theDates.push(randomDate());
        dataValues.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);    
    }

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [dataValues], {
        xaxis: {
        tickFormatter: function xAxisLabelGenerator(x) {
           return moment(theDates[x]).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
        }
      }
    });
});
```

In this example I'm using moment to format a random date and place these in order on the x axis. You'll note that since the dates are completely random they may not even be sequential yet they are all evenly spaced. If you want the fiddle version [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/uv0fq2kf/2/). Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the data at fixed distances regardless of the x values is known as [categories mode](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html) in Flot. For this mode you can give the data in this form and do not need to give ticks seperately:

```
var data = [
    ["2016-02-18 11:53:49 AM", 12, "<b>X</b> : 2016-02-18 11:53:49 AM |  <b>Y</b>: 12"],
    ...
]
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b76sjfjy/1/) for a full working example (btw: I upgraded the flot.js file you used in your fiddle from 0.7 to 0.8.3).